# Ruby on Rails 4: Devise with Users Controller, Couldn't find User with 'id'=sign_up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm getting this error: `Couldn't find User with 'id'=sign_up` when I'm trying to go to **localhost:3000/users/sign_up** in my URL browser.

I have a separate Users Controller that I generated...

I did this:

```
rails g devise:controllers users
rails g controller Users show
```

I didn't touch the controllers that was produced by devise.

In the regular users controller that I created, I have this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

In my routes:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get 'users/:id' => 'users#show', as: :user
end
devise_for :users
```

My `rake routes` looks like this:

```
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
                 user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
```

It makes sense why I'm getting an error because :id is sign_up in my URL, I just don't get what I should be doing to fix this.

And of course, it'll always give me an error for anything after **localhost:3000/users/** because of the id in my show method in users controller

Comment: change the sequence of your routes keep `devise_for :users` above the `devise_scope` and then try

Comment: @Deep did not work. I didn't think the sequence would matter?

Comment: It matters when we have similar routes.

Comment: @Deep ah. I see. Yeah it didn't work. I even restarted the server

Comment: Can you change the show route do you need to keep it the same?

Comment: @Deep oh wait... let me retract that. I was testing it in sign_out... but i tried sign_in/sign_up and it works... why does sign_out not work?

Comment: @Deep what would I need to change sign_in or sign_up if I don't use it? Would it be better if I change it? What's your suggestion or best practice that I should do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83652/discussion-between-deep-and-hellomello).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a separate `users_controller` which doesn't belongs to `devise` so `devise_scope` is of no use there. If you need to use any devise controller action then `devise_scope` is useful. So just make your routes as this:

```
devise_for :users
get 'users/:id' => 'users#show', as: :user
```

The sequence of routes matters when we have similar routes. In devise the routes `sign_up`, `sign_out` are defined as `/users/sign_up(.:format)` so suppose you visit `sign_up` url then it would check with the routes in devise and will find the match there. So it will redirect you to that route. Now if you enter `/users/1` it will find in devise routes but it will find no match so ultimately it will map to your route and if there is no route defined as such it will throw error..

Glad this helped. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help and explanation!